# PhpStorm inspect code without external usages

Tags: phpstorm

I have the version 2019.2 of PhpStorm. I always liked to inspect code to see if something got broken. But now the inspect code takes much longer time because of the task "Processing external usages...". It takes me about 5 minutes to fulfill the inspection.

In the settings window, under `PHP | Inspections` I don't find any inspections which match to this task. I would like to run code inspection but without processing external usages, is that possible? Which inspection settings match to this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a new (or improved?) inspection: `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Inspections | PHP | Unused | Unused declaration`

It does take [time & memory to run](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-47889#focus=streamItem-27-3644088.0-0) as it checks quite a bit of code.